# how to change the div class according to the value coming from the model

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

how to change the class of css bootstrap according to the value

i want to show div in green color if value is OK else in red color.if status = "OK" then it should be   `<div class="small-box bg-green">`
 else   `<div class="small-box bg-red">`

```
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="small-box bg-green">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>No-7 @Model[4].status </h3>
                    <p>@Model[4].devEUI.Substring(4)</p>
                    <p>@Model[4].datetime</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i>
                        <img src="~/images/TransIcon.png" />
                    </i>
                </div>
                <a href="@Url.Action("7", "Transformer")" class="small-box-footer">Trans info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expression i.e.

```
<div class="small-box @(Model[4].status == "ok" ? "bg-green" : "bg-red")">
```

Comment: `<p>@(Model[4].datetime != null  ? Model[4].datetime != null : "NA")`

Comment: error - there is no implicit conversion between bool and string

Comment: `<p>@(Model[4].datetime != null ? Model[4].datetime  : "NA")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `class="small-box @(@Model[4].status=='ok' ? "bg-green" : "bg-red")"`

```
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="class="small-box @(@Model[4].status=='ok' ? "bg-green" : "bg-red")">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>No-7 @Model[4].status </h3>
                    <p>@Model[4].devEUI.Substring(4)</p>
                    <p>@Model[4].datetime</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i>
                        <img src="~/images/TransIcon.png" />
                    </i>
                </div>
                <a href="@Url.Action("7", "Transformer")" class="small-box-footer">Trans info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```